# MFMailComposeViewController in Swift does not dismiss

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, ios8

This is sample code:

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func showEmail(sender : AnyObject) {
    var emailTitle = "Test Email"
    var messageBody = "This is a test email body"
    var toRecipents = ["a.nakhimov@gmail.com"]
    var mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
    mc.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
    mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)

    self.presentViewController(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func mailComposeController(controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error:NSError) {
    switch result.value {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.value:
        NSLog("Mail cancelled")
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved.value:
        NSLog("Mail saved")
    case MFMailComposeResultSent.value:
        NSLog("Mail sent")
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed.value:
        NSLog("Mail sent failure: %@", [error.localizedDescription])
    default:
        break
    }
    self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
    // self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

When I push the button, the function **showEmail**  is executed and appears the form for send email. If I click "Send", then everything works fine - mail is sent, then the function **mailComposeController**  is executed. NSLog displays the label **"Mail sent"** and the initial screen reappears.

If I'm in the dialog box of send mail, click **"Cancel"** button, then dialogue does not disappear, function **mailComposeController** does not work, two buttons - "Send" and "Cancel", becoming gray color and so it stays.

What wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be bug in iOS 8. Same problem exist in Objective-C also.

Comment: Damn! :-) I already went through hundreds of different options! :-)

Comment: Is this bug still persist?, I am facing same issue in Xcode6.0.1

Comment: The presentingViewController is the one responsible of dismissing the presentedViewController, not self

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to dismiss `self` instead of the `MFMailComposeViewController` (which isn't self).

Replace:

```
self.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

with:

```
controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

in the delegate method.

Comment: Just tried: **controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)** and **controller.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true)** - no change, MFMailCompose does not dismissed :-(

Comment: My problem is **didFinishWithResult** not fired.

Answer (score 2):

Bug has been resolved. Everything is working as expected in iOS 8.1+ and Xcode 6.1+

The following fires and works fine

```
extension MainViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
        switch result.value {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled.value:
            NSLog("Mail cancelled")
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved.value:
            NSLog("Mail saved")
        case MFMailComposeResultSent.value:
            NSLog("Mail sent")
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed.value:
            NSLog("Mail sent failure: %@", [error.localizedDescription])
        default:
            break
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```