# MFMailComposeViewController crashing iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using MFMailComposeViewController to send an email in three different view controllers in my app. In all controllers when running on a device with iOS 7.1/7.0 the app runs with no problems. On iOS 8(on a device) the app crashes when I try to dismiss the mail controller in the delegate method in only one of the controllers(the others still work). If I add a test controller by using a segue from the controller that crashes I can then present and dismiss the mail controller but if I then try to pop the new test controller the app crashes with the same problem. The crash logs indicate random objects that are getting sent messages related to tableview such as:

```
[UITraitCollection numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176061380
```

The error shows the object changing so in this case says UITraitCollection but other times might show 
CALayer or some other random object.

Search results appear to show that this issue is fixed [MFMailComposeViewController in Swift does not dismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341881/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-does-not-dismiss) but it obviously is not in this one strange case.
I have tried adding the mail controller as a property and as a global as per [MFMailComposeViewController in Swift does not dismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341881/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-does-not-dismiss) but this doesn't fix the issue either which is no surprise because the error I am getting is not the same as this error.

My code to present the mail controller is

```
func showMailController(productGroupName: String, manufacturer: String, pn: String, name: String, companyName: String, userName: String) {
    let mailComposer = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposer.setToRecipients(["test@test.com"])
    mailComposer.setSubject("subject")
    let con = "Hello!"
    mailComposer.setMessageBody(con, isHTML: false)
    self.presentViewController(mailComposer, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and my delegate method is:

```
extension CompetitiveXREFViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
}
```

}
(I have also tried self.dissmiss.. and using the save mail controller property self.mailController.dissmiss..)

It's behaving as if the mail controller is being released and then random tableview messages are being sent to that address but I did try holding the mail controller in a property as well as global variable. And once again, if I move the mail controller display to a new controller then I can show it and dismiss it but any attempts to then dismiss the new regular view controller(presented via a segue) also crashes the app with random objects getting tableview methods.

Comment: Is the view controller thas is presenting the compose view controller a table view controller? Or at least a `UITableViewDataSource`?

Comment: No, it is a UIViewController subclass which is also a UITextField,MFMailComposeViewController and a UITableView delegate.

Comment: Andrew Monshizadeh you are a life saver. I commented out where I set the tableview delegate and now it works. There is an issue there and I now know where to look. Thank you!