# Xamarin.ios: MFMailComposeViewController somewhat crashes when dismissed

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I found myself at a very strange problem. In the application we are developing, there is a feature to send the mail from the app itself.

According to Xamarin recipes, the MFMailComposeViewController is the way to go for the Xamarin.ios.

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/email/send_an_email/

As it seems there is a problem with just some of the devices, however the pattern is to me unclear.

While pressing the button "Send" or Cancel, the Finished delegate is called. This part should normally dismiss the MailViewController.

On some of the devices the behaviour is as expected, the Mail controller is removed from the screen and the underlying controller is displayed.
On some devices however, the mail controller stays on top, and the app is not responding anymore. The debugger does not show anything.

Did anybody face this issue so far? Could this be somehow solved? I was reading some of the similar behavior in obj-c or swift code, however their solution did not help me.

[MFMailComposeViewController in Swift does not dismiss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24341881/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-swift-does-not-dismiss)

This is my code:

```
private void OnSendMailClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
        {
            string receiptText = trx.isReversed ?
                Utilities.GetTransactionAndRefundReceipt(trx, manager) : Utilities.GetReceipt(trx, true);

            var mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();
            mailController.SetSubject(String.Format("Receipt number: {0}", trx.STAN));
            mailController.SetMessageBody(receiptText, true);
            mailController.Finished += OnSendResult;

            PresentViewController(mailController, true, null);
        }
    }
```

and the Finished delegate looks like this:

```
private void OnSendResult(object sender, MFComposeResultEventArgs e) => e.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
```

### Edit

It turns out the problem is in the inheritance of the MFMalComposeViewController, which is inherited by UINavigationViewController.
As I am already using an underlying UINavigationcontroller this causes sometimes problems. As soon as I find a suitable solution I will post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved. It turns out, that the problem lied in the nuget package I was using.

https://github.com/jdehlin/Xamarin-Sidebar/

From the version 1.9.4 the behavior is easily reproducible with an iPhone device.